# how to change the border design

Tags: html, border

Is it possible to change the border design...sorry i clicked the sent button

```
<html>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-bottom:3px;">
                <strong style="font-size:12px;">Test A : <br/></strong>
                Test1 
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom:3px; padding-top:4px;"> 
                <strong style="font-size:12px;">Test B:<br/></strong>
                Test2 <br/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="padding-left:5px;padding-bottom:3px;">
                <strong style="font-size:12px;">Test A : <br/></strong>
                Test1 
            </td>
            <td style="padding-left: 5px; padding-bottom:3px; padding-top:4px;"> 
                <strong style="font-size:12px;">Test B:<br/></strong>
                Test2 <br/>     
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</html>
```

Comment: For border styling http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_border-style.asp http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_border.asp

Comment: Assuming you just want to style a table's border with CSS there is a beautiful generator site right here: [HTML and CSS Border Style Wizard](http://www.somacon.com/p141.php)

Comment: Your question is not very clear as to what exactly you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You need to make sure that your questions are formatted as a **question**!

Comment: It still is not a question. What border design are you talking about? The table's? Change how?

Answer (score 2):

Try styling your table with CSS...

get rid of the border="1" property on your table and try something like:

```
<style>
    table {border: dashed 1px red}
</style>
```

You can also style the table's child elements:

```
<style>
    table {border: dashed 1px red;}
    td {border: solid 2px blue;}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

cant see any question in you post, but according to the headline: yes, there are different border-designs, take a look at [this](http://www.css4you.de/border-style.html). for a table you could do something like this with css:

```
table{
  border 1px solid #000;
  border-collapse: collapse; // for don't having double-lined borders between table-cells
}
table td{
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```